# What Follower should I pick to complement the skills of my class?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the strengths and weaknesses of each follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower)

With every class, what follower should I take so his general skills will complement mine?

For example, as a Barbarian, I shouldn't pick the templar as a follower, because it would just be 2 melee attackers, so our skills are mostly the same.

So who should I pick as a barbarian? (and with every other class, since we are talking about it.)

Answer (score 0):

As a ranged class (wizard) I feel the Templar is a much better choice for me, he tanks a bit and distracts enemies and also has some useful heals. Also, templar gets 1h & shield instead of a single 2h slot for the other 2 - which means potentially more mods to help either him or me (magic find etc.)

Not sure why he would be a bad choice even if you're melee char, the other followers don't have heals and it doesn't really hurt to have an extra distraction for mobs. Possibly if the followers die easily in NM+, or you need crowd control help, then the others may be a better option.

Personally, I am more likely to just switch out the templar when I can't listen to his self-righteous BS any more though he does a good job in his role :p