# Best follower for battle wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the strengths and weaknesses of each follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower)

i wanted to ask you guys whats the best follower for a melee wizard in diablo 3? I got The scoundrel yesterday so im wondering is he or the templar more useful?

Answer (score 2):

I really like the templar on my wizard , helps tank