# Best follower for Barbarian and best way to equip them

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the strengths and weaknesses of each follower?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67598/what-are-the-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-each-follower)

It seems to be the consensus for the average Barb in Inferno that the best follower is Enchantress, for the Armour buff as most, like myself, are building their character for surviabilty (LOH, armour, high res, block%, vit).  What I find is that she does seem to die very quickly.

What is the best way to equip her? At the moment I have her with a high dps 2h weapon with high int/vit, and the 2 rings and amulet also have high int/vit. So she is doing around 5k dmg and has 30-40k hp.

Comment: I do not like the enchantress mostly because of the way I like to build my characters, which is to focus on critical hit damage. Because of this, I almost exclusively bring along the scoundrel for his addition to my critical hit chance.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, all followers in Inferno are just tissue paper buff puppets.  Let's face it, even the Nephalem are pretty vulnerable in Inferno.  I recommend stacking as much Vitality as possible, and when possible adding in Magic/Gold find as it benefits you.  Assume she will get wiped out in any fight that lasts more than 5 seconds.  In the current design I don't know that is avoidable.  I also believe that enchantress is best simply because of the control abilities.  When you consider the DPS of high level monsters, the 2-3 seconds of not getting obliterated is worth it all.  Paltry heals (Templar) or puny DPS (Scoundrel) just don't compare.

Comment: Templar does a great job blocking doors for wizard or DH, and he can survive quite well outside of area effects (desolation, plagued et al)

Comment: Have you found elites on Inferno that don't have at least one of those affixes?  In my experience (and maybe I'm just unlucky), I find each fight to be a game of "the ground is lava".  If I'm lucky they don't jail/wall me to stand in it, but even if they don't you can count on my follower standing there till death.  I prefer the few seconds advantage to try and burn one down, and then I usually end up kiting the rest and whittling them down (if I don't die).  A sad strategy, but it seems to me the only way to play Inferno.

Comment: Quite often I find them w/o the area dmg affixes - even if they do, I try to use templar to delay, fire a few shots then run away so he teleports to me before dying. Of course, this is for ranged; for barb I agree sorc or scoundrel is better but more due to IAS or crit auras.

Comment: I've tried stacking str/vit on my templar and he's ended up with 90k health and 3k armor, which makes him last long enough usually that my DH can take out most elites.  Any fight longer than a few seconds however, and he'll usually die.