# Are there items similiar to charms?

Tags: diablo-iii

In Diablo 2 (I believe they came in LoD) there were Charms. Items that gave you buffs by just having them in your inventory. Is there anything even close to this system in Diablo 3, or is it only your gear and passives that give you stats.

Comment: Please do explain how this question violates any of the rules on Gaming.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There are no items similar to D2's charms in Diablo III**. The only items that are really worth keeping in the inventory as you adventure are potion stacks.

In earlier iterations of Diablo III's design there used to be a charm-like system called "talisman" that did not occupy inventory space, see on the left here:

[image: talisman screenshot]

([image source](http://www.d3library.com/Items/Charms.html))

But [it was removed after Blizzard were not happy with how it worked](http://www.diablowiki.net/Talisman). There were vague hints by Blizzard that it might return, but at the moment it's not a confirmed future feature.

Comment: It's interesting how much effort Blizzard will put into a feature before deciding it's not working and scrap it entirely. Starcraft Ghost anyone? It's frustrating to see such teasers, but I think it's cool that they put more work into features that eventually get cut than some studios put into entire games!

Comment: @Wikwocket The fact that they put that much effort into the implementation just to scrap it leads me to think they really do put a lot of thought into their products to ensure they are releasing something that is worth the wait.

Comment: @Wikwocket Every software company runs into these issues. You decide to go forth with an implementation of something (Regardless of if its a game mechanic or some business software), complete it and test it and then you find it diminishes the effectiveness of other things. Its pretty common actually

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is nothing like charms in D3. Perhaps they will look to add something similar in the future.

Currently it is only your gear and passive skills that give you stats.

You can also get some bonuses from equipping your follower with certain gear (i.e. magic find, gold find, etc...).

Comment: Interesting, follower gear can benifit you as well?

Comment: @Emerica. [you get 20% of the +MF, +Gold and +XP gear of your followers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66833/what-benefits-are-there-in-giving-your-followers-better-magical-weapons-shoul).

Comment: @Oak Good eye, I was just searching and found that. Good thing I didn't post the question haha

Answer (score 4):

Charms went through a few different iterations in Diablo III, but were ultimately [scrapped as being an uninteresting mechanic.](http://forums.battle.net/thread.html?sid=3000&topicId=27810240882&forumId=12007&postId=278054184421#2) Bashiok left the possibility that they may return, but with the [Mystic having been scrapped as well](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68395/empty-spots-in-the-last-2-cities), I wouldn't hold my breath.

Well, unless she returns..

Answer (score 2):

No, Diablo 3 does not currently have any items which give you benefits just by having them in your inventory.  As you said, these were added to Diablo 2 after its release, so they may come to Diablo 3 at some time, but I think the designers have said that they weren't too happy with the way they worked.

Comment: Yeah, I think putting a limitation to the number of them you can carry may help.